# Is it possible that $(xy +1, y^2 -1)$ has a Grobner basis with respect to some specific term ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that this ideal in any polynomial ring does not have a Grobner basis but is it possible to construct a term ordering where it does have a Grobner basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Groebner basis is $(x+y,y^2-1)$ using total degree.